# when does docker-compose use currently built images and when does it remake the local image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

with a dockerfile like so

```
FROM python:3.5.5-alpine

ARG CONTAINER_HOME_DIR

ENV CONTAINER_HOME_DIR=$CONTAINER_HOME_DIR

WORKDIR $CONTAINER_HOME_DIR

COPY wall_e/src/requirements.txt .

RUN apk add --update alpine-sdk libffi-dev && \
    apk add freetype-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir Cython && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt &&  \
    apk --update add postgresql-client


COPY wall_e/src ./

CMD ["./wait-for-postgres.sh", "db",  "python", "./main.py" ]
```

If I then use this dockerfile with `docker-compose`, at what point does docker-compose determine that it needs to re-create the docker image that it will use to make the docker container from that image?

Will it remake the docker image if I make changes to the `wall_e/src/requirements.txt` file or will it remake the docker  image if I make a change to the `RUN` line or the make a change to any files located in `wall_e/src` or even change the `COPY` LINE entirely or the `CMD` line?

Lets assume that I am using `docker-compose up` and I am not using the option `--force-recreate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the image is built, docker-compose will not look into your dockerfile.
It will use that image, and only apply its configuration (`docker-compose.yml`).

So let's say you `docker-compose up`, then edit your `docker-compose.yml` file, your `requirements.txt` and your `dockerfile`, when you use `docker-compose restart` only the docker-compose.yml changes will be taken into account.

If you need to rebuild your image, you'll have to use specifically :

```
docker-compose build [my_service]
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker will not rebuild images unless 1) instructed to do so, or 2) if the named image doesn’t exist.

That being said, when you rebuild, it will attempt to rebuild based on any cached information it has, and does not re-process steps unless the dockerfile has been modified, or if a file referenced via `COPY` has been modified. Any subsequent steps after a re-processed step will also be re-processed, because the build process basically creates new sub-images based on sub-images built from previous steps in the dockerfile.

However, if you specify `—no-cache`, it will re-process all steps in the dockerfile.

Comment: If you change a file that is `COPY`ed in, it invalidates the cache starting there.  If you edit `requirements.txt` and re-run `docker-compose build` it _will_ re-run the subsequent `pip install`.  You should rarely if ever need the `--no-cache` option.

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed my answer